# How to run an autohotkey script in Python (2.7)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, autohotkey

I'm trying to run an autohotkey (ahk) script in Python 2.7 but nothing seems to work. All online sources I've found are either outdated or overly complicated.

Has anyone found a way of doing this? I just want to run a couple of simple scripts that activates windows and opens applications. E.g:

```
IfWinExist, Command Prompt - python ...
    WinActivate
```

Update:

I've tried downloading pyahk:

```
ahk.start() # Ititializes a new script thread
ahk.ready() # Waits until status is True
ahk.execute(mw._['cwd']+"winActivate_cmd.ahk") # Activate cmd window
```

error: can't load autohotkey.dll

as well as trying this:

```
import win32com.client # Import library / module
dll = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoHotkey.Script") #Creating DLL object?
dll.ahktextdll() #no idea what this is doing...        
dll.ahkExec("WinActivate, Command Prompt - python")
```

pwintypes.com_error invalid class string

Comment: I've added this as an edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you should be able to just launch autohotkey with the script as a parameter using [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
subprocess.call(["path/to/ahk.exe", "script.ahk"])
```

You'd have to check the autohotkey docs but this seems like it ought to work.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Didn't think it'd be that easy :) Also, turns out my .ahk file didn't actually work but I've just tried it on a simple hello world

Comment: No problem! Occam's Razor and all that; sometimes the simplest solution is the best one!